# Providing counterexamples to the claim: If $|A \cap B| < |A|$ then $|A|>|B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, examples-counterexamples

I'm having problems answering the following question:

> Give a counter example to show that the following
>   statement is false:
>
> For any sets $A$ and $B$, if $|A \cap B| < |A|$ then $|A|>|B|$

Presumably we can't be sure whether $|A|>|B|$ as we don't know how many elements there are in $B$ which aren't shared with $A.$

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track. See what happens when $A$ and $B$ have no elements in common at all. Can you build a counterexample in this case?

Comment: Well let's assume that |A| = 5 and |B| = 9| And |A Intersect B| = 0, then |A| is not > |B|.

Comment: Yep, this works just fine.

Comment: I've provided a fairly specific example. Is there a more abstract counterexample I could provide?

Comment: @MartinRand Your example is fine, but it would perhaps be more elegant to use a smaller example, like two disjoint one-element sets.

Comment: @MartinRand Take any three *mutually exclusive* (aka disjoint) sets $X, Y, Z$ where $0 < \lvert Y\rvert \leq \lvert Z\rvert$ . Call $A=X\cup Y$ and $B=X\cup Z$.  Done.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea. So you should be able to construct your counterexample if you start with some sets that already satisfy $|A\cap B|<|A|$, and then add enough fresh elements to $B$ to make $|A|\not>|B|$.